# How to configure a Pyramid application behind Apache HTTPS Proxy

Tags: https, mod-wsgi, pyramid, proxypass

I have a Pyramid application running on an internal server using mod_wsgi-express. The address internally is http://172.31.15.111:6543/myapp/

I want to make it available externally using Proxy and SSL. So I have the following Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName myapp.org

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # proxy pass /myapp to the internal:6543/myapp
    ProxyPass           /myapp       http://172.31.15.111:6543/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse    /myapp       http://172.31.15.111:6543/myapp/

    <Proxy *>
        allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyTimeout 1200


</VirtualHost>
```

The problem that I have is that when I use "request.route_url()" or "request.host_url" it resolves to HTTP and not to HTTPS.

I am using Waitress with the following configuration:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
listen = localhost:6543
```

I tried also:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
#listen = localhost:6543
host = 172.31.15.111
port = 6543
url_scheme = https
```

I also tried having request headers in apache:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Scheme https
```

But I get the same result. Any idea how to resolve it is highly appreciated.

Comment: For background reading, have talked about proxying to mod_wsgi-express in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html Ignore that it talks about Docker, still applies anyway.

Comment: I had a look and I tried with "RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443" and 
"RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Scheme https" to but I get the same result.

Comment: Hi Graham Dumpleton. I fixed it based on your link. What I missed was the --trust-proxy-header as part of the mod_wsgi-express setup. Thank you very much for the help